# admob TEST ad -> No ad to show

Tags: ios, sdk, admob, ios-simulator

This is not a duplicate..

In the new Admob SDK (Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK 7.31.0) when you show a test ad it shows you a **REAL ad(!)** and it adds an annotation with the words "Test Ad"

But sometimes, when you really needs an ad to show (for testing purposes) - you get Error code 1 "Request Error: No ad to show."

It **IS** a test ad. I can see the words "Test Ad" when the test shows! (when it was showed, now nothing shows =[)

SO, my question is:
Does someone knows a workaround?

[image: example of annotation in an interstitial ad]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know the answer... It's a bug in the SDK. =[

[see here](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/banner?hl=he)

> The easiest way to load test ads is to use our dedicated test ad unit
>   ID for iOS banners: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716
>
> It's been specially configured to **return test ads for every request**,
>   and you're free to use it in your own apps while coding, testing, and
>   debugging. Just make sure you replace it with your own ad unit ID
>   before publishing your app.

---

**EDIT**: I've found and solved the **REAL** issue.

When you create an ad, you have two options:

1. Add it to view hierarchy **AFTER** it loads an ad ---> *works always*
2. Add it to view hierarchy **BEFORE** it loads an ad ---> *BE CAREFUL WITH THIS ONE*

If you choose the second approach you have to **set the frame** of the ad view **to a visible size** (width + height) and you must ensure that `isHidden = false`

My problem was that I wanted to animate the showing of the ad. I added the banner to UIStackView and set its `isHidden` to `true`.

I used the delegate so when ad was loaded I animated the `isHidden` to `false`. All looks good, but apparently the Google Mobile Ads SDK validates that the ad is visible before it loads an ad --- my ad view was **NOT** visible! so I got the `Request Error: No ad to show`

> **Thanks Google for "great" documentation =[**